# Android-x86 won't install on VirtualBox

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, android-x86

I have a problem with Android-x86 and VirtualBox.

I had never worked with Linux before, so I don't understand what's happening. After creating a new virtual machine and choosing "Install Android-x86", I get this:

[image: Kernel panic]

My settings:
[image: configuration]

I've tried using android-x86-4.2-20130228.iso and android-x86-4.2-20121225.iso

What's wrong?

Comment: What are your VirtualBox settings? Also, this question relates to virtual machine installation, which should be in Super User.

Comment: I have added preference to the post

Comment: Your settings look fine. This tutorial uses similar settings: http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/

Comment: Yes, I have tryed a few configurations, but I always have this error after choosing instalation. So this tutorial can't help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that virtualization was turned off in my BIOS settings. It must be on for Android-x86 to run on VirtualBox.

Comment: I am having the same problem as @Vitaliy Ermakov, so I went into my BIOS settings. Under "Virtualization" the only options I had were "VT-x" and "Disable." I selected "VT-x," rebooted, turned on VT-x acceleration in VirtualBox, and I still had the same problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: @ZoveGames I think, in you case it's doesn't work because android x86 requires VT-d technology.

Comment: No, I actually solved this problem. I was using the unstable 4.4 version. I got the stable 4.0 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Your specific virtualization options may vary, but this solution worked for me.  I had two virtualization options that were unchecked and checked them both and the android vm works! This was probably the cause of other VM issues I've had before and had postponed the BIOS investigation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Download Android 4.0 for EEEpc and you don't need Virtualization technology. It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the other answers – virtualization seems to be a requirement of later Android x86 versions, as 4.2 still worked without.

Here's what solved it for me, thanks to the other answers:

- Make sure virtualization is enabled in your system BIOS. If not (or if you're unsure), go to your BIOS and look for a setting named "Virtualization", "VT-x" or "AMD-V" and make sure it's enabled.
- Then, in your virtual machine settings, go to **System > Acceleration** and check **Enable VT-x/AMD-V***.
- On the same page, I left the **Nested Paging** option checked and set the paravirtualization interface to **Legacy** (as on my tried-and-true 4.2 VM). Different settings might work here, too – I didn't investigate further.

With these settings I can boot into the live installation and launch the installer.

Comment: Best answer so far. Still I cannot make any of Android x86 versions run on my intel processor (Core2 Duo) that doesn't have virtualization capabilities

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Make Sure Graphics Controller: VBoxSVGA**

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, and think I have the solution for you. I am on Windows 8.1 64bit, if you disable Hyper-V it works.

Go to Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off, find Hyper-V in the list, remove it and restart windows.

Answer (score 1):

Change Settings - System - Pointing Device to "USB Tablet"!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.  I had VirtualBox version 4.3.8 installed when I initially tried the installation and failed.

After I upgraded VirtualBox to version 4.3.18, the installation went through without a problem.  From my research, you need to have version 4.3.10 or above.

Comment: Not quite right -- trying to run Android 4.3 on VirtualBox 4.3.10_Ubuntu93012 still leads to kernel panic.

Answer (score 0):

kernel panic 
you must set your computer to ...

Enable Intel Virtualization Technology in bios
then set operating system in virtualbox to 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Yes setting bios for Virtualization technology = enabled allows for circumvention of this road block along the highway of Andriod.

Answer (score -1):

i had also this problem best solution is that if u hava used 10 gb for android x86 then when it ask during installaion then select space less than 10 gb or whatever u used. It ask during installing.

Comment: it doesn't answer by any means the question, whatever you are trying to say.